Weed and Feed for lawn hit my Catmint plants... how do I fix it?
Husband used weed and feed on lawn now my catmint plants are droopy... I suspect they got hit with the weed and feed... is there anything I can do?

It depends on what is in the weed and feed.  Sometimes the 'weed' is just cornmeal, and I doubt that hurts catnip.
More often though, it's something like 2,4-D, which is toxic to catnip.  The half-life of 2,4-D in soil is only 1-14 days though, so if it is that you would be able to replant catnip there again soon.
Do you still have the Weed and Feed package?  What is the 'weed'?
